# Types of deployment in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, deployment

What are the types of deployment we have in asp.net?

Till now what I am doing?

I use to publish my website in any folder than copy paste the compiled file to the inetpub folder [where my website is configured with the IIS]. I am not sure what kind of deployment this is, is it XCOPY? But I am not using any command line tool.

Comment: Not gonna answer this, i don't think its a proper question. You should research a bit. http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/default.aspx for instance.

Comment: @Crypth I understand that this question is too subjective but I am not sure the technique I am following, I have read XCOPY and Web deployment wizard technique and I feel like XCOPy is something which I am doing. I am not expecting a complete theoritical answer for this question, I am seeking a clue which would help me to study in the linear manner.

Comment: Very well, there are many opinions and ideas of how to go about deploying. Microsoft themselves does indeed condone xcopy in some cases, but theres other who do not: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

Comment: @Crypth +1 for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have the following options

**xcopy deployment**
Compile your asp.net application and copy all the files to your server. You can do this by using FTP or shared directories. (Or anything else to transfer files.)

**WebDeploy**
You have the possibility to deploy your asp.net webpage directly form your Visual Studio. If you go to "Build" and you choose "Publish Web". To be able to to do this you have to configure your server before. But this works automatically after you have set up everything. It's very handy since your deployment becomes easy to rebuild. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx

**Web Setup - Installer**
Visual Studio provide also the option to build an installer. This works like installing usual software on your windows computer with the installer wizard. (See the link)
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx

**Manage multiple server**
There is also a way of managing the deployment of multiple servers. It seems to be a bit more complicated but could be interesting for professionals. (Check out on Google **Microsoft Web Farm Framework 2.0**

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: yes, what you are using is called xcopy deployment. Even though you do not type xcopy *.* ... it is still a 'plain copy' and therefore called xcopy deployment.